# How to pass JSON array from HTML page to JSP

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp

At the moment I am using Instagram API and Querying a Location. The JSON Array gives me back 20 objects wiht Longitude, Latitude and Location name.

I currently have a JSP that has a MapBox. I'm looking to place all the 20 objects as markers within the MapBox.
The trouble I'm having at the moment is how do I pass my JSON array to my JSP so my JSP can work with it.

**index.html**

```
$.ajax({
url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=' + token,
dataType: 'jsonp',
type: 'GET',
success: function(data) {
//Pass object and load JSP Page
},
error: function(data){
console.log(data); // send the error notifications to console
}
```

**location.jsp**

I'm looking to have the following. But I don't know how to access JSON Array from JSP

```
foreach(var data in jsonArray)
{
    var marker = L.marker([data.Longitude, data.Latitude]).addTo(map);
}
```

Comment: You can try this answer and solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/27766930/3587865](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27766930/3587865)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3116118/6743203